# If $S \subset X$ does a subsequence of $S$ converge in $S$ or in $X$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space and let $S\subset X$ be a compact space.

By definition, $S$ is compact implies that for all sequences $(x_n)$ of $S$, there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_{\alpha}})$ that converges.

**My question is** Does $(x_{n_{\alpha}})$ only converge in S or can it converge in X?

Comment: By definition, $S$ is compact implies that for all sequences $(x_n)$ of $S$, there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_{\alpha}})$ that converges and whose limit lies in S.

Comment: what if S is open in X?

Comment: @aribaldi: That makes no difference at all.